# KStream value filtering based on a KTable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to filter a KStream based on the values of a KTable. This is similar to the `SQL IN` clause. I went through the documentation for KStream filter method but i could not find a way to filter based on a KTable.

PS. I do not want to use kSQLDb

Comment: You need to use Processor API to get access to the StateStore. Then you can lookup values, and chose to forward the data in your processor based on those results. Otherwise, you need to do a stream-table join, then filter that

Answer (score 1):

In KAFKA Filter is a **Stateless Transformation Operation** and it is pretty simple to implement it in both KStream and KTable.

### Basic Definition

Filter KStream → KStream and KTable → KTable

Evaluates a boolean function for each element and retains those for which the function returns true.

```
KStream<String, Long> stream = ...;

// A filter that selects (keeps) only positive numbers
// Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
KStream<String, Long> onlyPositives = stream.filter((key, value) -> value > 0);
```

You can refer this simple example for the usage of filter to chuck out the odd numbers from an input stream.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/SumLambdaExample.java

Comment: Please try to understand my question.

Comment: Sorry. I misread it in other way. You can define a table from a Ktable source containing a list of values that you are interested using a predicate and inject that value into stream.filter method using the lambda expression. Haven't done such use case in my coding, or else I would have given you the code snippet.